# Problem with events (Cannot read property 'Event' of undefined)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have one big problem. Anytime i try to use MyContract.events.MyEvent i have same problem (first picture). I dont know what to do with it
.
[Truffle console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCwM2.png)

[Solidity code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYKhl.png)

I've got web3@1.21 v. and 5.8 solc compiler. I dont know what might be wrong.

Comment: Please embed the error message and the code as text to make them easy to find and to test.

Comment: Did you find solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

Use the function this way:

```
MyContract.contract.events.MyEvent
```